# Natural isomorphism of a monoidal category

Tags: category-theory

The definition of a Monoidal Category from "Categories for the working mathematician" says that it is a category equipped with tensor products, associative up to a natural isomorphism.

What does "associative up to a natural isomorphism" mean in this scenario? I read the wikipedia definition of "up to" but cannot understand it when we are talking about categories.
I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break it down.

A natural isomorphism is a natural transformation that is also an isomorphism. Or alternatively, a isomorphism (technically a family of isomorphisms) that is natural.

Associative "up-to natural isomorphism" means, somewhat informally, that $(A\otimes B)\otimes C$ is not necessarily equal to $A\otimes (B\otimes C)$, but there is an isomorphism $\alpha:(A\otimes B)\otimes C\to A\otimes (B\otimes C)$ which is natural.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!

Comment: See also [monoidal category](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monoidal+category) in nLab, in particular the **associatiors* $\alpha$ are the thing Dave is talking about.

Comment: That seems like a very good resource - thank you for the suggestion.